# exec not works in pdftk but in commandline

Tags: php, pdftk

I have some pdf file in folder C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\uploads\1\AllFiles and pdftk exists in the same folder.In case of merging by commandline `C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\uploads\1\AllFiles\pdftk *.pdf output 123.pdf` works.
but in php i am using

```
$command = '/uploads/1/AllFiles/pdftk *.pdf output 123.pdf';    
exec($command);
```

it doesn't work and also in case of full path.
how to solve this.thanks in advance.

Comment: does $command  work in the commandline?  It doesn't matter  if a different command works in the command line, only if the command you are using from php works in the command line.  Your $command has an absolute path so does it work absolutely .. lol .. if that doesn't work in the command line, then why would it work in php using exec()?

Comment: no $command  doesnt works on commandline.but with 'pdftk *.pdf output 123.pdf' thats i said.

Comment: What is the error, when you use the full path?

Comment: You may wish to use the full absolute path?  Seems you are missing "C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\" from $command.  I think your confusion is you think php is running inside PhpProject1?  I am not sure where the "working dir" is right off hand for exec but just use the full path in this case.